# How do I group stops into a parent station in GTFS?

Tags: gtfs

In [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) (defines public transportation schedules and geographic information), a station (`parent_station`) contains several stops (`stop_id`).

I am analyzing Paris GTFS data. All `parent_station` fields are blank value.

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT parent_station FROM stops;
+----------------+
| parent_station |
+----------------+
|                |
| 0              |
+----------------+
```

**How do I specify parent staions for stops (or group stops into parent station)?**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM stops LIMIT 10;
+---------+-----------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------------+
| stop_id | stop_code | stop_name                          | stop_desc                                 | stop_lat  | stop_lon | location_type | parent_station |
+---------+-----------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------------+
| 1166824 |           | "Olympiades"                       | "91 rue de Tolbiac - 75113"               | 48.826948 | 2.367038 |             0 |                |
| 1166825 |           | "Olympiades"                       | "91 rue de Tolbiac - 75113"               | 48.826948 | 2.367038 |             0 |                |
| 1166826 |           | "Bibliotheque-Francois Mitterrand" | "Face au 62 rue du Chevaleret - 75113"    | 48.829831 | 2.376120 |             0 |                |
| 1166827 |           | "Bibliotheque-Francois Mitterrand" | "Face au 62 rue du Chevaleret - 75113"    | 48.829831 | 2.376120 |             0 |                |
| 1166828 |           | "Cour Saint-Emilion"               | "Cour Chamonard - 75112"                  | 48.833314 | 2.387300 |             0 |                |
| 1166829 |           | "Cour Saint-Emilion"               | "Cour Chamonard - 75112"                  | 48.833314 | 2.387300 |             0 |                |
| 1166830 |           | "Bercy"                            | "Place du Bataillon du Pacifique - 75112" | 48.840543 | 2.379409 |             0 |                |
| 1166831 |           | "Bercy"                            | "Place du Bataillon du Pacifique - 75112" | 48.840543 | 2.379409 |             0 |                |
| 1166832 |           | "Gare de Lyon"                     | "Gare SNCF - 75112"                       | 48.844652 | 2.373108 |             0 |                |
| 1166833 |           | "Gare de Lyon"                     | "Gare SNCF - 75112"                       | 48.844652 | 2.373108 |             0 |                |
+---------+-----------+------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------+----------------+
```

The stop `1166830` and `1166831` should belong to the same parent station for the same longitude and lantitude.

One idea comes into my mind. With a given radius (say `r`), two stops belong to a same station if their distance (say `d`) is less than `r`, i.e., `d < r`.

Any better ideas?

Comment: It seems to me that those are simply duplicates, given that all of the identifying stop information is identical. Is there any reason to keep the two distinct stop IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are sure that stop entries are not duplicates but they are stops located inside station, I propose following solution:
Find list of different stops with same name and location, then edit to indicate the first stop in the list as a "station" and other remaining stops in the list as stops inside the station.

[Reference document](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference) will help you to do it. As an example I give you following edited (shown with ^^^^) rows:

```
| 1166830 |  | "Bercy"| "Place du Bataillon du Pacifique - 75112" | 48.840543 | 2.379409 | 1 | |
                                                                                          ^^^
| 1166831 |  | "Bercy"| "Place du Bataillon du Pacifique - 75112" | 48.840543 | 2.379409 | 0 | 1166830 |
                                                                                               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: @SparkandShine was above answer helpful to you? Also curious to know what you are trying to do with GTFS data for Paris? Do you work for the agency?

Comment: thx. I don't work for the agency, but use Paris GTFS as my simulation trace.  Imagine that install a wireless access point (transmission range *r*) for a station which might be consisting of several stops (`stop_id` in GTFS). I would like to know which stops can be grouped into a station.